# javascript calculation of person ages and heights

Tags: javascript, performance

I need to take sum of all the person's ages and heights.

Input Array:

```
[
  {
    "personId": 1,
    "ages": [
      1,
      4,
      5
    ],
    "heights": [
      1,
      1,
      2
    ]
  },
  {
    "personId": 2,
    "ages": [
      4,
      2,
      2
    ],
    "heights": [
      1,
      4,
      2
    ]
  },
  {
    "personId": 2,
    "ages": [
      2,
      1,
      1
    ],
    "heights": [
      12
    ]
  }
]
```

Desired Output:

```
[
  {
    "type": "ages",
    "values": 22
  },
  {
    "type": "heights",
    "values": 23
  }
]
```

My Solution (Which is working perfectly fine):

```
var agesTotal = 0;
var heightsTotal = 0;
var resultArr = [];

var sourceArr = [{personId: 1, ages: [1,4,5], heights: [1,1,2]}, {personId: 2, ages: [4,2,2], heights: [1,4,2]}, {personId: 2, ages: [2,1,1], heights: [12]}];

for(var i = 0; i < sourceArr.length; i++){

    if(sourceArr[i].ages){

        if(i == 0){

            resultArr.push({
                type: "ages",
                values: agesTotal
            });
        }

        for(var n = 0; n < resultArr.length; n++){

            if(resultArr[n].type == "ages"){

                resultArr[n].values += agesTotal + sourceArr[i].ages.reduce((partialSum, a) => parseFloat(partialSum) + parseFloat(a), 0)
            }
        }
    }

    if(sourceArr[i].heights){

        if(i == 0){

            resultArr.push({
                type: "heights",
                values: heightsTotal
            });
        }

        for(var n = 0; n < resultArr.length; n++){

            if(resultArr[n].type == "heights"){

                resultArr[n].values += heightsTotal + sourceArr[i].heights.reduce((partialSum, a) => parseFloat(partialSum) + parseFloat(a), 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This above code of mine is producing the correct response, but it seems like so much processing and unoptimized.

What I need is the best & optimized possible solution for this operation

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` and `reduce` remove all the effort of the loops, and patching up the output format.

You seem to deal with the possibility of `ages` or `heights` properties not existing in the input array, which adds some complexity to the `reduce` call.  As written in the snippet, it deals with both.

**IF the data always contains these**, then you can simplify to:

```
ages += person.ages.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
heights += person.heights.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
```

**If the array always exists but could be zero length**, then you will need to provide an initial value for `reduce`:

```
ages += person.ages.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
heights += person.heights.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

```js
const data = [{personId: 1, ages: [1,4,5], heights: [1,1,2]}, {personId: 2, ages: [4,2,2], heights: [1,4,2]}, {personId: 2, ages: [2,1,1], heights: [12]}, {personId: 3, heights: []}];

function sumAgesAndHeights(data) {
    let ages = 0;
    let heights = 0;
    data.forEach(person => {
        ages += person.ages?.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) ?? 0;
        heights += person.heights?.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) ?? 0;
    })
    return [
        {
            "types": "ages",
            "values": ages
        },
        {
            "types": "heights",
            "values": heights
        }
    ];
}

console.log(sumAgesAndHeights(data))
```